# Stack smashing detected error on function return

Tags: c

I'm making a project for a class in C [ANSI-90]

for some reason, I get a stack smashing error, I know it's gcc protection for buffer overflow, or accessing a memory that shouldn't be accessed as far as I've understood.

but I can't find why.
i found out that it aborts once i return from a function that is supposed to parse only the first word of input into a command using strtok
this is what i got:

```
    int getCommand(char *p, commands *cmd)
{
    int i = 0;
    char lineCopy[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    char *cmdName;
    strcpy(lineCopy, p);
    cmdName = strtok(lineCopy, "\t \n");
    if (cmdName != NULL)
    {
        while (cmd[i].func != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d",i);
            if (strcmp(cmdName, cmd[i].name) == 0)
                return i;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    i=-1;
    puts("return error"); /* Just to check I'm reaching here, and i do */
    return i; /* ERROR */
}
```

input example to recreate:

```
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

i will be happy if you could point and explain what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what `MAX_LINE_LEN` is set to, but it practically doesn't matter. You have no guarantee that `lineCopy[MAX_LINE_LEN]` is large enough to fit the contents of `p`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alexander pointed out, I didn't allocate memory for `linecopy`, fixed with:

```
char *lineCopy = malloc(strlen(p));
```

Comment: This should be `malloc(1 + strlen(p));` to make room for the null terminating byte. Better yet, just use [`strdup`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html), if available.